# На Linux в браузерах через proxy не работают Websocket

Tags: linux, websocket, proxy

На работе использую корпоративный прокси сервер и обнаружил что не работают Websocket в браузерах

При этом в консоле все ок, то есть сам прокси-сервер нормально пропускает трафик для ws\wss , но создается ощущение того что браузер не использует прокси для Websocket

---

В качесте эхо сервера использовал сайт:

- https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester

**Тестировал в браузерах:**

- FireFox 94
- Chromium 96
- Midori 9.0
- Opera 81

**ОС:** Manjaro linux

Через консоль проверял так: ( ссылка на команду [wscat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat) *использует nodejs* )

```
wscat -c "ws://demo.piesocket.com/v3/channel_1" --proxy http://mycompany.domain:1234/
```

---

Самое интересное что на винде и Mac OS ( Safari ) все работает нормальное, то есть проблема проявляется только в **Manjaro linux**

Уже перерыл кучу тем , но так и не понял как решить эту проблему )

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему с помощью браузера [waterfox](https://www.waterfox.net/)
В нем все работает через прокси